# Dropping the key column of right data frame after merging

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm looking for a simple way to get rid of the key column of the right table after merging it with another data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

users = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3], "name": ["Mark", "Elon", "Jeff"]})
orders = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "user_id": [2,3,2,1,1,3]})

orders_full = pd.merge(left=orders, right=users, how="left", left_on="user_id", right_on="id")
orders_full
```

This is the result:

[image]

I guess there is a pythonic elegant code to have better column names as result (avoid renaming e and dropping each column manually)

good solution: id, user_id, name

even better: order_id, user_id, user_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the `id_x`/`id_y` issue, you can `set_index` on the appropriate columns and use `join` instead:

```
orders_full = (
    orders
   .set_index('user_id')
   .join(users.set_index('id'), how='left')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   user_id  id  name
0        1   4  Mark
1        1   5  Mark
2        2   1  Elon
3        2   3  Elon
4        3   2  Jeff
5        3   6  Jeff
```

To finish with your desired column names, you will have to do a rename e.g.

```
orders_full = (
    orders
   .set_index('user_id')
   .join(users.set_index('id'), how='left')
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={'id':'order_id', 'name':'user_name'})
)
```

Output:

```
   user_id  order_id user_name
0        1         4      Mark
1        1         5      Mark
2        2         1      Elon
3        2         3      Elon
4        3         2      Jeff
5        3         6      Jeff
```

Answer (score 2):

More "elegant" way could be not use `.merge` but simple `.map`:

```py
orders["name"] = orders["user_id"].map(users.set_index("id")["name"])

print(orders)
```

Prints:

```
   id  user_id  name
0   1        2  Elon
1   2        3  Jeff
2   3        2  Elon
3   4        1  Mark
4   5        1  Mark
5   6        3  Jeff
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since you want to rename anyway, I think this is the most elegant/explicit:

```
pd.merge(left=orders.rename(columns={'id': 'order_id', 'name': 'user_name'}),
         right=users.rename(columns={'id': 'user_id'}),
         how='left', on='user_id')
```

Output:

```
   order_id  user_id user_name
0         1        2      Elon
1         2        3      Jeff
2         3        2      Elon
3         4        1      Mark
4         5        1      Mark
5         6        3      Jeff
```

Comment: Actually I was avoiding the id of the right (since it's duplicated: user_id = id_y)

Comment: @Victor I see, the second part of my answer still stands, since you have to somehow define which column is which, better to it **before** the merge to be explicit. Then they don't have to drop anything. I updated.